# In Symfony form, how can I check as default a ChoiceType checkbox?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, choicefield

How can I make a radio button or checkbox  in a form be selected as default, without the user selecting any of them?  Obviously the users could check what they want if they wish to. I have looked in the documentation and have found the `preferred_choices` function but I believe this has another aim. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default value on the property of your object link to your form or override it with the [data option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data)